# Recognizing this kanji: ホイールが【?】いよく回転

Tags: kanji, handwriting

[image]

Can you help me please?
I can't recognize this kanji with red arrow

Comment: Choko has answered, but just for a note, a backwards search on the next characters いよく would have found this in EDICT: http://beta.jisho.org/search/%3F%E3%81%84%E3%82%88%E3%81%8F

Comment: Didn't know there were EDICT faces that allowed wildcards.  Nice!

Answer (score 6):

> [勢]{いきお}い

です・・・。

（文字数が足りない・・・）